I can't use Flutter_session when i add it to dependencies
I want to use the function about FlutterSession().set() & FlutterSession().get().
flutter clean
flutter pub get

reopen VS code.
still can't use FlutterSession

flutter pub get:

I can't use the flutter session method. Or flutter has other ways to directly use session.request or session.get like python?

That simply means that the null safety is not supported by flutter_session package. You can clone the flutter_session code from github and make it null support then use it locally or you can use https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_session_manager
